# How can I extract variables from a map? where the key is the name of the variable and the value is his value

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a big map and i need to pass to SQLite db but i can't pass it like a map due to a provider. I need to extract a lot of variables from it. Is there any way to make it automatically?

I am trying with all the properties of a map, converting in two Lists but nothing happens.

An example

This is my map

`Map map<String,dynamic> { steve : 34, mark: 28, william : 56}`

How can I get the next vars

`int steve = 34; int mark = 28; int william = 56;`

Thanks.

//Due to the comments I'll try to explain better my problem.

I'll use a reduced example.

I have a SQLite db, I use a provider class to make all the operations.

This is my provider.dart

```
class WineBasicDataProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final SQLiteHelper _db = SQLiteHelper();

  List<WineBasicData> _items = [];

  Future<void> loadWineBasicData() async {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = await _db.wineBasicData;
    _items = data.map((wineBasicData) {
      return WineBasicData(
          id: wineBasicData["id"],
          name: wineBasicData["name"],
          tank: wineBasicData["tank"],
          date: wineBasicData["date"],
          grapes: wineBasicData["grapes"],
          comments: wineBasicData["comments"],
          finalConclusion: wineBasicData["finalConclusion"]);
    }).toList();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> addOrUpdate(
      dynamic name,
      dynamic tank,
      dynamic date,
      dynamic grapes,
      dynamic comments,
      dynamic finalConclusion,
      EditMode? editMode,
      [dynamic id]) async {
    final int idSaved = await _db.insertTaste(
      WineBasicData(
        id: id,
        name: name,
        tank: tank,
        date: date,
        grapes: grapes,
        comments: comments,
        finalConclusion: finalConclusion,
      ).toMap(),
    );

    final WineBasicData winebasicdata = WineBasicData(
      id: idSaved,
      name: name,
      tank: tank,
      date: date,
      grapes: grapes,
      comments: comments,
      finalConclusion: finalConclusion,
    );
    if (idSaved != 0) {
      if (editMode == EditMode.ADD) {
        _items.insert(0, winebasicdata);
      } else if (editMode == EditMode.UPDATE) {
        _items[_items.indexWhere((element) => element.id == winebasicdata.id)] =
            winebasicdata;
      }
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  Future<void> deleteTaste(int id) async {
    _items.removeWhere((element) => element.id == id);
    await _db.deleteTaste(id);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  List<WineBasicData> get items => [..._items];
}
```

Then, in other part of the project, when I call wineBasicDtaProvider.addOrUpadte() I need to pass all the variables (id, name,tank,date,grapes,comments,finalConclusion)

The problem is that in other tables much bigger than that example I have the data in a map like the next example. Basically the same map than the model without the id.

```
 Map currentBasicData <String,dynamic> {"name": "example", "tank": "N25" : "date": 125, "grapes" : "example1", "comments2: "example2", "finalConclusion" : 12.5 }
```

I don't know how to pass the data.

I hope it is better explained now.

Thanks

Comment: Not getting exactly your question..do u mean u want to store all value to variables?

Comment: Yes I think, all the key:value pairs into a independent variables, with the key as the name of the variable. It is possible?

Comment: Likely impossible in the general case. Even if you could do it, how would you even use that to do anything if you don't know which keys will appear? Can you give us more context? Your problem can probably be solved in another way.

Comment: I try to give you more context. Thanks.